# How can the users custom design reports?

Tags: reporting-services

I have some reports in my reportserver...
I was wondering  how can i let to Users custom design the reports

Answer (score 0):

You can create the DataSource objects on the reporting server and then give the users rights to the report designer.  That way they can access the raw data to create their own reports off of without giving them special access to the data.  They can build reports specific to them in a safe environment.

If you don't want to get that in-depth with your users, create the reports for them but put a few key parameters in the reports.  That way the users can filter or change the reports somewhat without doing any designing work themselves.  We use this to allow our users to report off of different years based upon the parameter they enter.  They can also change the report scope (one year, multi-year, one month, etc.) using these parameters.